# C# passing reference datatable to method makes all rows have the status modified

Tags: c#

I want to pass a datatable to a method. The method will change some values only on those rows that have not been modified by users from the GUI (=> only RowStatus Unchanged rows will be modified).

The problem: when I pass my datatable to the method, all the rows get the status Modified. I tried using the ref keyword to tell the app to work directly with the original table (pass by reference) instead of creating a duplicate.

I can also assure you that my table has all it's rows unchanged when I load data from my database to the datatable (I used the command dt.AcceptChanges => RowState Unchanged). The also checked that the rows persist being unchanged until my method is called.

This is how my function looks like in Form1:

```
public static void ReaplicConfigDoc(ref DataTable tabel)
{
     foreach (DataRow rand in tabel.Rows)
         if(rand.RowState == DataRowState.Unchanged)
              rand["Column"] = 56
}
```

This is how I call it in Form2:

```
SameNameSpace.Form1.ReaplicConfigDoc(ref SameNameSpace.Form1.DataTableOriginal);
```

Do note that I call this method from a second form Form2 that is in the same namespace as Form1. Also, Form2 can only be opened from Form1.

Comment: First note: forget `ref`; that has almost no bearing here; the only time that would be relevant is if you were *reassigning* `tabel`, i.e. you had a `tabel = ...` statement somewhere in `ReaplicConfigDoc`. Since you don't: you can just remove that completely: it does nothing useful, and causes confusion.

Comment: There are 5 possible values of `DataRowState`; added, deleted, detached, modified, and unchanged. You're not adding, deleting or detaching, so the only two relevant states are modified and unchanged. You're looping over all the rows, and *for the ones that are unchanged*: making a modification. It seems logical, then, that at the end of the operation: all rows (or at least those that weren't already added/deleted/detached) would now be: modified. So: isn't it working exactly as we'd expect?

Comment: Good day, @MarcGravell, regarding your first question: if I don't pass the table by reference (using ref keyword) doesn't the method create a duplicate table to use in it's body? I'm asking because this is how "passing by value vs reference and benefits of each" was explained to me when I learned C++.

Comment: @MarcGravell second comment: in my testing scenario I did not change any of the rows from the graphical interface and even put watches for each row that shows the state. This means that all my rows are unchanged before I call this function. but when it enters the function, all my rows become modified, so no row will have 56 assigned in the "Column" column because no row has "unchanged" in the function's foreach.

Comment: No, basically; but don't worry, this is such a common misconception that it is almost inevitable that everyone gets it wrong. Since `DataTable` is a reference-type, the thing that you're "passing by reference" is: the reference. As opposed to passing a copy of the reference. In either case, the table is not impacted or copied whatsoever. Passing a reference by reference here just adds an extra level of indirection to the object.

Comment: Re modified etc: did you check what the state of all the rows was *before* you did anything with it? were they perhaps already "modified"?

Comment: @MarcGravell regarding 3rd comment: thank you for explaining why ref is unneeded. I take it that only in  a tabel = 'DataTable value' I'd need it. Could you give me one more example where ref should me used in a function? The Microsoft docs are a bit confusing for a beginner like me.

Comment: not in the space available for comments here, no; "almost never" is probably a good default

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238359/discussion-between-razvan-ionescu-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: I think you have to copy datatables. Take a look at this article: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1037138/DataTable-Copy-Vs-DataTable-Clone-in-Csharp